# alias: extract options from command

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

Apologies for the bad title.  I couldn't come up with a better one.

I want to alias a command to another command, and extract options from the text of the command itself.  I realize this is unclear, so perhaps an example will help:

If i were to do something like this with `ls`,  I would want to be able to alias the following:

```
ll -> ls -l
la -> ls -a
lal -> ls -al
l -> ls
```

BUT

```
ls -> ls #allow this special case to not change
```

preferably, I would like to be abel to determine on my own whether to igrone part of the command, like I do with the `s` in `ls`. so, for example, I'd also like to be able to do with grep:

```
grepi -> grep -i
greps -> grep -s
grepis -> grep -is
```

we dont have to worry right now about options that take arguments, for example, its ok if `grepm` fails.

Comment: While not exactly what you're asking, unless you have a command that frequently changes the base command name, it will likely be easier to just set up a bunch of aliases in your `.bashrc` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following:

- Set `shopt extdebug`, enabling several debug options. The relevant one is: *If the command run by the DEBUG trap returns a non-zero value, the next command is skipped and not executed.* We need this to not actually try to execute the undefined `lal` command.
- A `trap` for the `DEBUG` signal, which is executed before any command is executed. Set the trap like this: `trap 'insane_magic_alias' DEBUG`.

The function `insane_magic_alias` parses the command about to be executed (in `$BASH_COMMAND`) and processes it, aborting execution of the actually entered command in the process by `return 1`, unless `type` says it exists, in that case we do nothing (and let it run).

```
# make sure to name this function appropriately...
function insane_magic_alias {
    local CMD=$BASH_COMMAND

    # make sure this isn't a command that exists
    if ! type "$( echo "$CMD" | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }' )" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then

        # handle calls to `l*`
        if [[ ${#CMD} -gt 1 && "${CMD:0:1}" = l ]] ; then
            # actual transformed program call
            ls -${CMD:1}

            # abort execution of undefined command
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    # either execute an existing command, or show the "command not found" message
    return 0
}
```

Result:

```
$ lal
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 danielbeck  staff    68  2 Aug 22:53 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 78 danielbeck  staff  2652  2 Aug 22:53 ..
```

Note that your bash thinks you have a job running for a moment just afterwards (if you print job information in your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you will notice this). Plus probably another few side effects that make this fail in any case not just a simple demo...

Comment: This is probably not something you actually wanted to do if you thought about possible side effects.